# OpenCV の make install の対象フォルダを変更する方法

Tags: python, ubuntu, makefile, cmake

環境
Ubuntu16.04

以下のようにOpencvをビルドすると、`make install`でcv2.soが`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so`にコピーされるのですが、これを`make install`でpython3.6の`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.so`
にコピーされるように変更したいのですが、どの部分で設定を変更すればよいのでしょうか。

以下行ったこと

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D ..
make 
make install
```

Comment: システムにインストールされている(デフォルトの)Python、もしくは別途インストール・利用しているPythonのバージョンはいくつなのでしょうか。OpenCVのビルド時に正しいPythonのパスを伝える必要がありそうです。

Comment: デフォルトのpythonは2.7ですが、python3.6でも使えるようにしたいと思い質問させていただきました。```make install```後には python2.7では```import cv2```が通っています。

Comment: cmake実行後に`CMakeCache.txt`というファイルが生成されていたら、その内容を質問文に追記してもらえませんか。

Comment: やりたい事は「インストール先の変更」ではなく「Python3向けにOpenCVをビルドする」だと思うのですが如何でしょうか。新規で投稿された質問もこちらに関連する内容のようですが、情報を整理した上で質問内容をもう一度見直してもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: 目的は「Python3向けにOpenCVをビルドする」との指摘の通りです。重複質問との指摘ですが、目的は同じですが様々な方法で利用できるようにしたいと思い、質問させていただいています。

Comment: ```CMakeCache.txt```は生成されていますが、内容が多いのでどの部分を記載すればよいのか教えていただけると助かります

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmakeのコマンドを実行後、メッセージに以下のようなPythonのサポート情報が表示されるので、それを見ると問題がどこにあるかわかると思います。

```
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
```

cmakeで、PYTHON2(3)_EXECUTABLE等のオプションを付けなかった場合は、ubuntu16.04付属のPython2.7とPython3.5を自動的に検出します。Python2.7の方が正常にビルドされてインストールされたのはそういう理由です。Python3.5の方はnumpyがインストールされていれば正常にビルドされますがnumpyがなければ何もしません。

Python3.6の方にインストールしたい場合には、cmakeにオプションを追加する必要があるので、opencvの公式マニュアルを探したところ以下の記載がありました。

```
[optional] Building python. Set the following python parameters:

PYTHON2(3)_EXECUTABLE = <path to python>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python<version>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2 = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python<version>
PYTHON_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython<version>.so
PYTHON2(3)_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/
```

最終的には、以下のオプションを追加するとpython3.6でmakeすることができました。オプションの値はPython3.6をソースからコンパイルして既定の設定でインストールした場合のものです。環境に応じて変更してください。

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/python3.6m
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

なお、簡単にopencvをインストールしたい場合はopencv-pythonというアンオフィシャルのパッケージがあるのでそれを使ってインストールすることもできます。

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: 「Python3.5の方はnumpyがインストールされていれば正常にビルドされますがnumpyがなければ何もしません」との指摘の通りnumpyインストールの前に```/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages```さえありませんでした。では、python3.6でも同様に```pip3 install numpy```で```/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages```にnumpyをインストールして、cmakeで上記のように設定すれば```make install```で```/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages```にcv2.soができるとの理解であっていますでしょうか。

Comment: Pythn3.6の場合は、cv2.so ではなくて cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.soという名前のものができます。その他にも細かいところで間違うことがあるので確認しながらやってください。

Answer (score 1):

インストール先の指定自体は`cmake`実行時に以下の変数で指定しています。

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
    ↓
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
~~~~~~~~~~
```

ただしこのパスの中で`.../lib/python<VER>/dist-packages/cv2.so`の部分はシステムデフォルト、標準PATHで見つかったPythonインタプリタのバージョンに対応したライブラリを生成して（区別が付くよう）バージョンに対応したディレクトリにインストールされているものと思います。

`Python3.x`向けにライブラリを作成・インストールしたいのであれば、[Yasuhiro Nijiさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/43236/3060)にもある通り、`cmake`実行時に`PYTHON3_*`で始まる変数でpython3の在り処を明示的に指定する必要があるのだと思います。

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3.6 \
        -D ..
```

---

指定すべき変数については[関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/43276/3060)の方で [sa-y](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/27410/sa-y)さんがコメントを付けているように、[公式のドキュメント](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)にも記載があるので確認してみてください。

> Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake
>
> 4. [optional] Building python. Set the following python parameters:
>
>    PYTHON2(3)_EXECUTABLE = <path to python>
>    PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python
>    PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2 = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python
>    PYTHON_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython.so
>    PYTHON2(3)_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/lib/python/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/

Comment: Ubuntu16.04には標準でpython3.5が入っているので、python3の方は指定しなければ付属のpython3.5になります。付属のpython3.5以外のものを指定したい場合に明示的に指定する必要があります。

Comment: ```CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local```は```make install```での実行時にインストールされる指定先との認識で大丈夫でしょうか。私のイメージだと```make```で```~/opencv/build/lib/cv2.so```ができ、```make install``で```/usr/local/lib/python-ver/site-packages```にcv2.soがコピーされるとのイメージだったので。