# import cv2でエラーが出ています: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv

環境
Ubuntu16.04
Opencv 3.4.0
python3.6

Opencvをビルドすると、cv2.soが`/home/user/opencv/build/lib/cv2.so`に作成されるのですが、これをpython3.6で使用できるようしたいと考えています。
python3.6のパスが通っている`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`にシンボリックリンクをこのように`ln -s /home/user/opencv/build/lib/cv2.so 　cv2.so`作成したのですがpython3.6で`import cv2`をするとエラーが以下のように出てしまいます。

以下エラー内容

```
import cv2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
I   mportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
公式のインストール手順通りに行った上で、 sudo make install 実行時に必要なファイルがインストールされなかったということでしょうか？

Comment: 質問 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43228/ との重複質問だと思われます。python2.7用にコンパイルされたcv2.soがpython3.6で正常に動作することは期待できないでしょう。

Comment: 上記に記載したのよぅにcv2.soのシンボリックリンクを記載しても動作しなかったので質問しました。重複質問との指摘ですが、目的は同じですが様々な方法で利用できるようにしたいと思い、質問させていただいています。

Comment: 重複候補: [OpenCV の make install の対象フォルダを変更する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43228/opencv-%e3%81%ae-make-install-%e3%81%ae%e5%af%be%e8%b1%a1%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%ab%e3%83%80%e3%82%92%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: @pkoko 先の質問は cv2.so を目的の場所にコピーするための方法についてのご質問であり、こちらの質問は目的の場所にある前提の上で `import cv2` を成功させたいというご質問である、という認識で間違っておりませんでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 質問内容を整理するとおっしゃる通りです。重複候補の方は```make install```で目的の場所にコピーする方法。本質問は```make install```を使わなかった場合で、代わりに目的の場所にシンボリックリンクをはったのに```import cv2```がうまくいかないということです。

Comment: 関連質問<https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43228/opencv-%E3%81%AE-make-install-%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95> 
 で@cubick さんが「Pythonインタプリタのバージョンに対応したライブラリを生成」と記載されているので、バージョンを意識していない```/home/user/opencv/build/lib/cv2.so```へのシンボリックリンクを作成しても機能しないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cv2.soはpython2用のものです。pythn3.6用はcv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.soという名前で作成されます。pythn3.6用のコンパイルに失敗している以上どうやってもpython3.6では動作しません。